# Why does my HTML constructor object return [object Object] instead of [HTMLElementElement]?

Tags: javascript, html, object, constructor, return-type

## Background

I'm trying to make a completely pure JavaScript GUI for creating HTML content for learning purposes. The only real html in the file will be one `<script></script>` element. I'm almost finished, I think.

I made a custom HTML element constructor, but when I create an object, `[object Object]` is displayed instead of `[object HTMLWhateverElement]` when I do `alert(whatever);` (see the example below). I think that's preventing me from appending child elements to parent elements when both are made by the constructor.

### The main problem

If I could get HTML instances to append to HTML tags *and `element` instances*, then I would be very happy.

#### Constructor

```
function element(tagName) {
    var element = document.createElement(tagName);

    this.setText = function(elementText) {
        if(element.childNodes.length < 1) {
            var text = document.createTextNode(elementText);
            element.appendChild(text);
        } else {
            element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = elementText;
        }
    }

    this.removeText = function() {
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
    }

    this.setAttribute = function(attribute,value) {
        element.setAttribute(attribute,value);
    }

    this.removeAttribute = function(attribute) {
        element.removeAttribute(attribute);
    }

    this.appendTo = function(parent) { // Works but not on element instances of the constructor
        parent.appendChild(element);
    }

    this.details = function(){
        alert(
            "Type: " + element + 
            "\n\"typeof\": " + typeof(element) // Shouldn't need this right?
        );
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
ul = new element("ul");
ul.appendTo(body); // works fine if BODY is actually an HTML tag

alert(body); // gives me [object HTMLBodyElement] :)
alert(ul); // gives me [object Object] >(

li = new element("li"); // works :)
li.setText("list item text"); // works :)
li.appendTo(ul); // doesn't work >(
```

If I could just figure out how to append JavaScript-created (child) `element`s to other JavaScript-created (parent) `element`s, I'd be golden. I think it has to do with the return value of instantiated elements made by the constructor.

### EDIT

**1) Possible answer**

@carter-sand Thank you.
Adding a new `this.appendChild` method works but reinvents the wheel 
of HTML object's built in appendChild method.

**2) Possible answer**

@s4mok Thanks for the hint.
Changing `var element` to `this.elem` works but creates a 
funky interface:

```
li.appendTo(ul.elem);
```

vs.

```
li.appendTo(ul);
```

I'm trying to emulate a private member.

Both answers work but neither return the value [object 
HTMLWhateverElement] when I do :

```
alert(li);
```

Is there a way to reap the benefits of all of the above?

Comment: Note that because you add all the methods in the constructor (when they should be on its prototype), the reference to *element* is kept in a closure.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to add methods to the prototype in the constructor to emulate a class declaration? And is it bad to keep _element_ in a closure?

Comment: Adding methods to the constructor's prototype is how prototype inheritance works. It's OK to keep *element* in a closure (it kind of emulates a private member) but you may want to make it a public member for easier access.

Comment: Thank you everybody. You have been VERY helpful and I learned a lot from all your responses. For other readers, I chose @Andrew Sellenrick's answer because it completely and explicitly answers this specific question but all the other responders provided very very useful information as well if you are struggling with constructors in JavaScript, like I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns an instance of itself [object Object] when created using the "new" keyword. You can override that by specifically returning your element. However you will then need to change "this" to your element instead because "this" refers to the <strike>function</strike> new instance. Also as suggested it may be less confusing if you changed "element" to something else like "newElement".

```
function element(tagName) {
    var element = document.createElement(tagName);

    element.setText = function(elementText) {
        if(element.childNodes.length < 1) {
            var text = document.createTextNode(elementText);
            element.appendChild(text);
        } else {
            element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = elementText;
        }
    }

    element.removeText = function() {
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
    }

    element.setAttribute = function(attribute,value) {
        element.setAttribute(attribute,value);
    }

    element.removeAttribute = function(attribute) {
        element.removeAttribute(attribute);
    }

    element.appendTo = function(parent) { // Works but not on element instances of the constructor
        parent.appendChild(element);
    }

    element.details = function(){
        alert(
            "Type: " + element + 
            "\n\"typeof\": " + typeof(element) // Shouldn't need this right?
        );
    }
    return element;
}


ul = new element("ul");
ul.appendTo(document.body); // works fine if BODY is actually an HTML tag

alert(document.body); 
alert(ul); 

li = new element("li");
li.setText("list item text"); 
li.appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. This allows the return value of an instantiated to be `[object HTMLWhateverElement]`, and all the methods and properties of HTML DOM elements are accessible of the instances, including `.appendChild();`. This answers the question completely. Now I just need to learn more about prototype inheritance, like @RobG mentioned.

Comment: Worth noting that it's now pointless to call the function with *new*, since the new instance isn't used for anything and isn't returned. It also overwrites standard methods of HTML elements (such as *setAttribute*) and adds methods that may clash with future additions to the DOM [Node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) and [HTMLElement](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#htmlelement) interfaces. That's why libraries like jQuery keep references to elements as a property of an object (a "jQuery object") and don't extend the actual elements themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
ul = new element("ul");
```

The above line is instantiating the function element() and the instance which is assigned to ul is an **object** and not HTMLWhateverElement

```
ul.appendTo(body); // works fine if BODY is actually an HTML tag
```

The above works because your code is :

```
this.appendTo = function(parent) { // Works but not on element instances of the constructor
    parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

whereas the parent is **body**  and an HMTL Element and has a method appendChild, and the element that you are appending is the element from this line:

```
var element = document.createElement(tagName);
```

Why the below code does not work?

```
li = new element("li"); // works :)
li.setText("list item text"); // works :)
li.appendTo(li); // doesn't work >(
```

The answer to that is first of all **li** is not a HTML Element which the code

```
this.appendTo = function(parent) { // Works but not on element instances of the constructor
    parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

will fail since the instance **li** is not an html element but rather an object instance of function element()

Another error in this code is that you have a circular li.appendTo(li); which if you inspect your code, you are appending as child li to itself. something like a paradox or a circular dependency.

**EDIT:**

My Recommendation:

- First of all, maybe change the name of your "element" inside the function element to avoid confusion. :D
- Expose the **var element = document.createElement(tagName);** so that you could access it  from the parameter **parent** of  your method **appendTo** which will allow you to use parent.getTheExposedElement().appendChild ()

Comment: Thanks, that works but gives a funky interface. `li.appendTo(ul.element);`

Comment: instead of `li.appendTo(ul.element);` use `li.appendTo(ul);` and inside the appendTo function, access the element as `parent.element.appendChild(element);`

Comment: I just saw @Andrew Sellenrick answer, and I think that is the way to do it based from your requirements

Answer (score 1):

If I run your example, I notice the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<element> has no method 'appendChild'
```

This is because your custom `element` instance does not have the `appendChild` method that you're using in `appendTo`.  You need to add one to your constructor, like this:

```
this.appendChild = function(child) {
    element.appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it without reinventing the wheel?